# How do I reduce size of pdf merge

Tags: python, merge, pdftk, pypdf

I'm trying to merge a group of PDFs (Up to 1,000) per unique groups. Meaning, of 100,00 pdfs created I need them to be grouped at a practice/market level and to output a merged pdf file containing varying counts of merged pdfs.

My pdf file creation and loop works fine but when it comes to merging, i'm running into file size issues.

Tried doing this utilizing PYPDF but file sizes are way too large:

''''
def merge_pdfs(paths, output):
'''

Is there an alternative to PYPDF that also allows me to create read only pdfs of a smaller size?

I've used PDFtk , ghostscript , and pymupdf to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your files perhaps come from the same source or are generated in the same way, and therefore will have common internal parts, for example the same font data in each.

Try:

`cpdf -squeeze in.pdf -o out.pdf`

On the output. You could do the initial merge with cpdf too, but it’s not required.

If it must be done directly in python, pycpdflib can do it with `squeezeInMemory`.